# iOS button title color won't change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I'm creating a UIButton dynamically with the following code which creates it as per specified style.

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: 60, height: 30 )    
let button = UIButton(frame: frame)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
button.addTarget(self, action: "filterByCategory:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.categoryScrollView.addSubview(button)
```

With this button, I want to toggle the style when tapped.
The following code changes the background color but not the title color.
Any idea why title color won't change?

```
func filterByCategory(sender:UIButton) {

    if sender.backgroundColor != UIColor.blackColor() {
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    } else {
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because your button will turn back to `UIControlState.Normal` after you touch it, it become `.Highlighted`, then `.Normal`

You should set 
`sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Selected)`

to

`sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState. Normal)`

or, just set it for all the states since u did a check for color like

`sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: [.Normal,.Selected,.Highlighted])`

*Edit: Above doesn't work, can use `NSAttributedString` instead

```
if self.loginButton.backgroundColor == UIColor.blackColor() {
            let tittle = NSAttributedString(string: "Login", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()])
            loginButton.setAttributedTitle(tittle, forState: .Normal)
            loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        } else {
            let tittle = NSAttributedString(string: "Login", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
            loginButton.setAttributedTitle(tittle, forState: .Normal)
            loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
```

Comment: Setting Selected to Normal didn't work. I've tried setting Normal for both default and in the tapped function.

Comment: Hi :D how about set it for all state

Comment: Just tried. Same thing didn't change the title color. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: Ah yeah, i tried that and sadly it doesn't change as you said, my suggestion for now is set the `setAttributedTitle` with Attributed String with different color, maybe someone else can have other solution for this

Comment: No, because the problem is you forgot to set the text of your button title. `button.setTitle("My Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

Comment: I tried `setTitle` + `setTitleColor` at same time also it doesn't seems to work :/, it does change the tittle, but color stay the same

Comment: See here. It would work. http://www.codesend.com/view/b74358df9dd5a7805537d0e598dbfcfa/

Comment: Hi, seems like the culprit is the `setSelected` part, in the upper code there's no `setSelected ` so that it doesn't change to `.Selected` state :D

Answer (score 3):

I have find solutions for more than 4 to 5 hours but did not found anything and concluded this two points :-

- If you are giving title from storyboard and setting the title color from programmatically or custom class than it will no work. Solution for this is

1. You can set the title programmatically and change its color programmatically using simple setTitleColor() method.
2. Or else you can use storyboard for both setting the title and setting the color through foreground color.
3. And if you are using Custom Class that you can use Inspectable and set its value through programmatically and set the color for the title using solution 1.

- If you do not want to do this steps just change the button type to default and it will work in any ways you are setting the titleColor either programmatically or from storyboard

Answer (score 2):

For Swift

```
button.configuration?.baseForegroundColor = UIColor.yellow
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 1):

for swift 3

```
button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
```

Comment: @yonivav 2.5 year old answer, still working in Swift 5. Please check your code. Also reference https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623993-settitlecolor

Answer (score 0):

From the above described problem.
I came to a conclusion that the button you created doesn't have a title, so that's why you're not able to see changes in the title colour.

To resolve the issue:-

1. set title for the button
2. change title colour using UIButton property `button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that, in the latest Xcode **xib** by default button style is **Plain**. If we set it **Default** then we can use `.setTitleColor` property and we don’t need **NSAttributedString** for this.

In Swift 5, the accepted solution of this question looks like this -

```
    if loginButton.backgroundColor == UIColor.black {
        let title = NSAttributedString(string: "Login", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black])
        loginButton.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
        loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
    else {
        let title = NSAttributedString(string: "Login", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
        loginButton.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
        loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
```